# JSON cannot be decoded on server

Tags: php, android, json

I have created and Android app that has to communicate with my website using JSON. JSON (on client, Android side) looks like this:

```
private static String JSONSend(Context ctx, JSONObject obj, String ObjName, String address) {
    IHttpDispatcher disp = new HttpDispatcher();
    Vector<String> ss = new Vector<String>();
    String link = address;

    String locale = uzmiLocale(ctx);
    if(locale=="")
        return "";
    
    try {
        obj.put("Lokal", locale);
        ss.add(ObjName + obj.toString());
        String ID = disp.getHttpResponse_POST(link, ss);
        return ID;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Above method is called from here:

```
public static String sendReq(Context ctx, String txt, String number) {
    JSONObject jsn = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsn.put("TextPoruke", txt);
        jsn.put("BrTel", number);
        return JSONSend(ctx, jsn, "JSNSend=", "www.mysite.com");
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Everything works fine on my Wamp server, but after moving my php code to webserver, nightmare started! Apparently, everything is sent the way it should be, but on serverside this php code is creating problems:

```
if(isset ($_POST['JSNSend']))
{
$argument = $_POST['JSNSend'];

$json = json_decode($argument,true);
$broj = $json['BrTel'];
$jsnLocale = $json['Lokal'];
```

it seems that result of "json_decode" is NULL, but `$argument` equals

```
{"\TextPoruke\": \"sometext\", \"BrTel\":\"111\"}
```

So passed JSON string seems ok, but for some reason it can't be decoded on webserver. Can anyone help me with this? Why is it not working?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your JSON got escaped prematurely which triggers a bad syntax error.

If $argument is in the format you state, then the following procedure would work:

```
<?php

$s = '{"\TextPoruke\": \"sometext\", \"BrTel\":\"111\"}';

echo 'Without stripslashes:' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump( json_decode( $s ) );

echo 'With stripslashes:' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump( json_decode( stripslashes($s) ) );

?>
```

Result:

```
Without stripslashes:
NULL
With stripslashes:
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["TextPoruke"]=>
  string(8) "sometext"
  ["BrTel"]=>
  string(3) "111"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Disable magic_quotes_gpc](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php). This was a completely misguided ‘security’ feature that should never be used. It runs `addslashes()` on all user input, with the premise that this would solve SQL-injection problems (it doesn't).

If the server isn't yours and so you can't disable it, use the “Disabling magic quotes at runtime” hack on that link for now and consider moving to a new host.